# Android How to get values from deep link in android using java?

Tags: java, android, deep-linking

Android How to get values from deep link in android using java?
I am implementing deep link in my android app and now i want to get all parameter like after slash both.
my url = **www.exmple.com/poduct-name/prodcut_id**

**www.exmple.com/iphone/147895**

so i want to get id-147895 from above url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this--

```
 URI uri = new URI("www.exmple.com/iphone/147895");
 String[] spPath= uri.getPath().split("/");
 String idStr = spPath[spPath.length-1];
 int id = Integer.parseInt(idStr);
```

thankyou

Comment: its not working

Comment: please check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

For the `activity` that you want to start your deeplink processing with, put this intent filter inside the `<activity>...</activity>` in your manifest as follows:

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      <data
          android:host="www.example.com"
          android:pathPattern="/.*"
          android:scheme="https"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

Then inside your activity, if it's flagged as "singleTask" you'll be able to get the data from the intent, in `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` method, or if it's flagged as "newTask" you should call your parsing methods inside the `onCreate(...)` and getting the intent by calling `getIntent()` method. The parsing process will be something like this,
 1. For onCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.your_view);
   if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getData() != null)
   {
      //parse your data here,
      //it's the deeplink you want "https://www.example.com/..."
   }
}
```

2. For newIntent()

   protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
   {
      super.onNewIntent(intent);
      if (intent != null && intent.getData() != null)
      {
         //parse your data here,
         //it's the deeplink you want "https://www.example.com/..."
      }
   }